# Is it possible to load another page when you're creating a pdf with tcpdf?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, refresh, tcpdf

I'm trying to change the page, when you are downloading a pdf. Otherwise you can download a lot of pdfs. I'm trying to make something against the spam.

What I got now: I create a `id` for a `session`. This `session` is named by `idPDF`. I create the `idPDF` by getting the current *date* and *time*. When you're creating the pdf, the `idPDF` will go to an online *database*. When the `idPDF` is found in the online *database*, then you're no longer able to create a pdf.

Then it will *delete* a part of the page and create a button with a `php` function `isset`. With this button you can create a new `session` and start creating a new pdf.

But I need to reload the page, before it is giving me this button. So how can I reload the page (that my page can check the id) or start a `javascript` function on the html page(`fadeIn` with `jquery`)?
Does anyone understand my question?

**PS**: For the output of the pdf, I'm using 'FD'

pps. I'm new with TCPDF

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it!

I used a jquery onclick function. It was that simpel.. First I had some problems with the required fields, but I changed it with a function that I used as a filter. I could load another page or button when the function returned true. With the button I could created another session.